# Handling solicited and unsolicited communication messages

Tags: multithreading, communication, messaging

This is more of a conceptual question and doesn't apply to any particular programming language.

I have two entities communicating with each other, with three types of messages allowed:

1. Command Message: An unsolicited message commanding the other entity to do something.
2. Query Message:  An unsolicited message asking the other entity for information.
3. Response Message: A solicited message answering a query message from the other entity.

Now each entity has two threads:

1. Reader Thread: Reads messages.
2. Worker Thread:  Sends messages and does useful things

The two possible communication scenarios are:

1. Entity A sends a command to Entity B, and Entity A doesn't care what happens after.
2. Entity A sends a query to Entity B, and Entity A must wait until Entity B responds with the answer.

So the question is, how does the reader thread handle both solicited and unsolicited messages?

Unsolicited messages are easy to handle through events.  The reader thread can just fire an event on the worker thread saying it received a query or a command, and the worker thread can react accordingly.

Solicited messages are hard to handle though.  The worker thread sends a query, and must block until it receives a response or times out.  How does the worker thread let the reader thread know it is waiting for a response, and how does the reader thread tie a response back to a specific query from the worker thread and deliver that response back to the worker thread's execution?

I know this has been done a million times in other programs, so whats the standard practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I used Windows Azure Service Bus messaging entities as I am familiar with it, but in general this should be true with any Messaging system.]

Lets say your entity names are A and B.

1. Have 1 Topic (pub-sub entities) and 1 Queue for communication between A and B (as you need bidirectional communication) : Topic-A2B & Queue-B2A. A2B is for Commands from A to B or Queries from A to B and B2A, as the name says, is for Responses from B to A.
2. Typical Messaging Systems will offer MessageType property - for you to be able to set it and the later distinguish which type of messages you are reading and route it accordingly : [Example from Windows Azure ServiceBus Brokered Message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage.contenttype.aspx). Use that Property - to set whether its a Query or Command or Response.
   The idea here is - while receiving a message in B - you will receive using Subscriptions. You will have 2 threads reading - (one) reads only Commands  (theSecondOne) reads only Queries
3. For UnSolicited messages - as you said, its easy to handle. All you need to do is

   - A should send message to B with BrokeredMsg.ContentType="Cmd" and B should create a Subscription with a filter  and read and process
4. For Solicited Messages - like Queries (a feature called [Sessions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage.sessionid.aspx) will come handy here).

   - A should send Message to B with something like: **BrokeredMessage.ContentType = "Query"**
   - A also sets a correlation Id on the Message it sends to B: **BrokeredMessage.SessionId = "ABC456"**   <-- The Correlation Id for A to be able to correlate this message with
   - Now A will wait for response and expects B to also set
     **BrokeredMessage.SessionId="ABC456"** <--- The exact same value it had set earlier.
     using the  [AcceptMessageSession API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh293109.aspx)  - with the Session Id and a Timeout. Ex: Q_B2A_QClient.AcceptMessageSession("ABC456", 2 mins)
   - At the receiving end B should Create a Subscription with a filter  to be able to Receive these messages.
   - Once B receives the query - it processes and puts back the result in the Q-BToA
   - If B succeeds to put back the message in the Q-B2A in less than 2 Mins - then A will receive it and then you can orchestrate it further with a Callback method (as all of these are async methods - you will not need to use any Reader or Writer thread as you mentioned above - which will be a huge performance booster).

HTH!
Sree